# Drupal view render for user roles

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I created a user view and their roles and applied multiple roles to the users.

I do not want to show the (anonymous,authenticated user,role1,role2) in the

views output ,im trying to render using views_pre_render as well as

views_post_execute but its displaying as anonymous,authenticated

user,role1,role2,MyROLE1,MYROLE2 for the Roles column

I created a custom module

My code below :

```
  function customview1_views_post_execute(&$view) {
        $results = &$view->result;

      foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
        if ($view->name == 'list_users_roles') {

          $user_roles = $result->_field_data['uid']['entity']->roles;

        // print_r($result->_field_data['uid']['entity']->roles);
          $filtered_roles = array_values(array_diff($user_roles,array('anonymous user','authenticated user','role1','role2'))) ;

              $results[$key]->_field_data['uid']['entity']->roles['rendered']['#markup'] = $filtered_roles;
        }    
      } 
return $view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the views php module and filtered the required roles